# Read in Values from external file, add them, print results

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, import, addition

**Problem:**
I have 50 text files, each with thousands of lines of text, each line has a value on it. I am only interesting in a small section near the middle (lines 757-827 - it is actually lines 745-805 I'm interested in, but the first 12 lines of every file is irrelevant stuff). I would like to read each file in. And then total the values between those lines. In the end I would like it to print off a pair of numbers in the format (((n+1)*18),total count), where n is the number of the file (since they are numbered starting at zero). Then repeat for all 50 files, giving 50 pairs of numbers, looking something like:

`(18,77),(36,63),(54,50),(72,42),...`

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
from numpy import loadtxt, linspace
import glob, os

fileToRun = 'Run0'
location = 'ControlRoom6'
DeadTime = 3
LiveTime = 15 

folderId = '\\'
baseFolder = 'C:'+folderId+'Users'+folderId+location+folderId+'Documents'+folderId+'PhD'+folderId+'Ubuntu-Analysis-DCF'+folderId+'DCF-an-b+decay'+folderId+'dcp-ap-27Al'+folderId+''
prefix = 'DECAY_COINC'

folderToAnalyze = baseFolder + fileToRun + '\\'
MaestroT = LiveTime + DeadTime

## Gets number of files
files = []
os.chdir(folderToAnalyze)
for file in glob.glob(prefix + "*.Spe"):
    files.append(file)
numfiles = len(files)
if numfiles<=1:
    print('numfiles is {0}, minimum of 2 is required'.format(numfiles))
    raise SystemExit(0)
    
    xmin = 745
    xmax = 815
    skips = 12
    
    n=[]
    count=[]
    
    for n in range(0, numfiles):
    
        x = np.linspace(0, 8191, 8192)
        finalprefix = str(n).zfill(3)
        fullprefix = folderToAnalyze + prefix + finalprefix
        y = loadtxt(fullprefix + ".Spe", skiprows = 12, max_rows = 8192) 
    
        
        for x in range(xmin+skips,xmax+skips):
            count = count + y
            time = MaestroT*(n+1)
            
            print(time, count)
```

**Current output is:**
'ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
84
85         for x in range(xmin+skips,xmax+skips):
---> 86             count = count + y
87             time = MaestroT*(n+1)
88

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (8192,)'

However I did previously have this [running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565230/adding-lines-from-a-text-file-and-printing-out-result-using-a-for-loop-python), it just printing out thousands of seemingly unconnected numbers. Does anyone know how I can alter the code to acheive the desired result?

**EDIT: Data Set**

In order to make the example easier to use, I've made a dropbox with some dummy data. The files are named the same as it would be reading in, and are written in the same format (the first 12 rows with unuseful information). Link is [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nyg7yd4x7zq64qc/AAD89GptKx4CtIo21vEmXu1Aa?dl=0). I haven't written 8192 dummy numbers as I thought it would probably be easier and produce a nearer facsilime to just use the actual files with a few numbers changed.

Comment: you have wrong parenthesis in `((n+1*18)`, should be `((n+1)*18`

Comment: please edit your question such that it is a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); that is, please use some dummy numbers in arrays as the files, since we don't have your files

Comment: Re: the brackets... fair enough, that isn't written in the code anywhere, that was just me demonstrating what it would be). I'll edit it now

Comment: Re: MRE... As part of the problem may be reading in the files, wouldn't doing this lead to making a different solution to the example I was asking about. I could set up so the file was accessible?

Comment: sure, but try to isolate the problem

Comment: I think the problem lies in the parameters of the 2nd for loop, but I tried changing those and it just stopped compiling rather than produced an incorrect output (You can see a previous attempt at completing this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565230/adding-lines-from-a-text-file-and-printing-out-result-using-a-for-loop-python ). Think this is the maximum I can get the code down to before bits start to not work just from me reducing it wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to edit code as shown starting from 'xmin = 745':

```
xmin = 745
xmax = 815
skip = 12

for n in range(0, numfiles):

    total = 0
    
    x = np.linspace(0, 8191, 8192)
    finalprefix = str(n).zfill(3)
    fullprefix = folderToAnalyze + prefix + finalprefix
    y = loadtxt(fullprefix + ".Spe", skiprows= xmin + skip, max_rows = xmax - xmin)

    
    for x in y:
        val = int(x)
        total = total + val
    
    print(((n+1)*MaestroT), total)
```

Prints out as

18 74

36 64

54 62

72 54

90 47

108 39

126 40

144 35

etc.
Which fit my needs.